# How to force DevExpress chart to show labels only for available values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, devexpress, data-visualization

*Let me try to explain the problem:*

- We have a [DevExpress scattered point chart](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2975):

[image: DevExpress scattered point chart]

- To which we need to bind the following data:

[image: data for DevExpress scattered point chart]

We need to show the first column `provider id` as X axis' series label.

Now, if we look at the chart, there're only four places where the X axis' series label is required however, there're multiple X axis' series labels.

> We need to show the X axis' series labels only for the points for which we have data on Y axis.

It's understood that the chart is automatically adjusting the X axis' series label as numbers.

How can one force chart to show labels only for available values?

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this, adjust the [`Series.ArgumentScaleType`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/DevExpressXtraChartsSeriesBase_ArgumentScaleTypetopic) property and set it to `Qualitative`.

[source](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T396432)